# write logs from python script (using logging module) to hive tables in azure hdinsight

Tags: python-3.x, azure, logging, hive, pyspark

I am fairly new to the logging module in python and azure hdinsight environment.

I am wondering about efficient process to write custom logs generated while running a custom python module/algorithm to hive tables in azure environment.

Is there any way to write all intermediate logs generated while running a custom python module at once at the end of the run? Will this approach help to save time as we are not connecting to hive table and writing log every time a log message is generated.

Or are there any handlers exist for this task?

Or any other recommended approaches?